# How can I hide the back arrow in the navigation bar's back button?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I have a navigation controller for which I'd like to override the default back arrow image and text. Basically, instead of the `< Back`, I'd like to hide the little `<` arrow, and just show the `Back` text. I've been able to replace the back arrow with another image, so I figured i'd just try to replace it with an image and then set the image to match the color of the background. How can I accomplish this?

In AppDelegate.swift I have this:

```
extension UINavigationItem{
    override open func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        let backItem = UIBarButtonItem()
        backItem.title = ""
        backItem.image = UIImage(named: "icons8_burger")
        self.backBarButtonItem = backItem
    }
}
```

In the viewDidLoad() for the controller that we are sent to when the button is clicked, I have this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let burger = UIImage(named: "icons8_burger")

        navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = burger
        navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = burger
    }
```

So, any ideas how I can accomplish this? I haven't found what I'm looking for thus far.

Any advice appreciated!

Comment: You need to hide the default back button and replace with custom left bar button item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do ,

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = nil
navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = nil
```

or

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "")
navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage(named: "")
```

Then by default iOS use `<` as default image.

To remove this image you need to add blank transparent image. I used sample from [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/54/Blank_Canvas_on_Transparent_Background.png) and google image reference is [here](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=T9FHXY3XPLO48QP2oLHIAw&q=transparent%20blank%20image&oq=transparent%20blank%20image&gs_l=img.3..0j0i8i30l2.120157.121964..122236...0.0..0.118.658.0j6......0....1..gws-wiz-img.......0i67j0i7i30j0i8i7i30.l4Yeyya_BUo&ved=0ahUKEwjNuuvMkevjAhUzXHwKHXZQDDkQ4dUDCAY&uact=5#imgrc=2qqBwWGWG9MgLM:)

Now reduce the image pixel size to `(1,1)` and add in your assets and use below code.

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "Blank")
navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage(named: "Blank")
```

Here **Blank** is the same image name in my asset.

Comment: Both this and Korona's answers worked for me, and i'm actually going to use Korona's, but since this was posted first and also works I will mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use an empty image object like below,

```
    let mask = UIImage()
    navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = mask
    navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = mask
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the appearance - both `backIndicator*` vars are read-only.
Try the next code-only approach. Tested on iOS 15.2

```
private func setupNavBar() {
    let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    let blankImage = UIImage.withColor(UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0))

    navBarAppearance.setBackIndicatorImage(blankImage, transitionMaskImage: blankImage)
}

extension UIImage {

    static func withColor(_ color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
        let onePx = pixelsToPoints(1)
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: onePx, height: onePx)

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        context!.setShouldAntialias(false)
        context!.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
        context!.fill(rect)

        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return image!
    }

    static func pixelsToPoints(_ pixels: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        return pixels / UIScreen.main.scale
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Apply emply image to `navigationController`

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "")
```